# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I have tried using custom pipe.This is my pipe file

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/user';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { isNgTemplate } from '@angular/compiler';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'my-pipe'

})
export class MyPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  isEqual = false;
  api: ApiService;

  transform(post_id: number, users: Observable< User[]> ): any {
   // users = this.api.getUserList();
    users.subscribe(user => user.filter(userss => {
      if (userss.id === post_id && post_id !== null) { this.isEqual = true; } else {
        console.log(this.isEqual + ' ' + ' hataa');
      }
    }));

  }
```

All i want is nonexistent users cant post.Therefore i trying user's id equalize with post's userId.Here is my html code

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userId">User Id</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id ="userId" name="userId" required [(ngModel)]="posts.userId">
     <!--<div   class="tetx text-danger" *ngIf="!isEqual" >Invalid Id!!!</div>--> 
      <div  *ngIf=" my-pipe: posts.userId " >

Invalidd


      </div>

    </div>
```

But unfortunately I get this error:

> [Angular] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: Your code has no signs of it having toUpperCase in there. Where exactly are you using it?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let u of  users_s |  my-pipe " >  i got error in this line

Comment: Please poste your full stack trace. As text, not as image.

Comment: @trichetriche i posted like this with intent to being more understandable

Comment: @trichetriche but if necessary; i can poste all my code

Comment: @cmyldz that's not up to you to decide, as you can see you missed the whole point of your error

Comment: @cmyldz I only want your error trace, that's all

Comment: i don't get you want to pipe u or users_s? so what is post_id you pass as value to your transform?

Comment: @FatemeFazli posts_id refer to posts.userId.I have 6 users  1- 6 respectively.

Comment: Also i try *ngIf="my-pipe : posts.userId" instead of *ngFor in above but  i got same error

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from Angular compiler that tries to compile your template.

Choose another name for your pipe, i.e. `myPipe`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
```

...

```
*ngFor="let u of users_s | myPipe"
```

And you can't use pipe without passing value to it:

```
*ngIf=" my-pipe: posts.userId "
```

it should be something:

```
*ngIf="postId | myPipe"
```

Comment: I got this error >> [Angular] Identifier 'myPipe' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Comment: `@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'`

Comment: Yes ; I changed like you said

Comment: Is it Angular language service error? Try to reopen your editor. Do you have any runtime errors?

Comment: red line appears under the  myPipe

Comment: *ngIf="postId | myPipe "  : I tried this but unfortunately error happened [Angular] The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found.Similar to red line appears below pipe name

Comment: You should add that pipe to declarations array of that module where you declared your component

Comment: Should I add like component? I did but same error didnt vanish

Comment: `@NgModule({ declarations: [SomeComponent, ..., MyPipePipe]...`

Comment: It worked .Red line vanished when i write *ngIf="postId | myPipe"